# Update an input field when another input field is updated

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I can't get this to work.

I got two forms, "mult" and "mult2" with a script making some simple calculations running through both. Both fields are dependent on data in another form called "recipe".

The thing is, i can actually get one of the forms to work doing it like i have done (see all my code under here) - the weird thing is that it's only mult2 that works and does all the calculations. Mult1 is not doing anything. The fields that needs to be updated in the end is "gravity" and "gravity2" - and only "gravity2" gets updated with the result of the calculation.

I know it's some long code bits here, but hope you can help me..

Here is the "recipe" form:

```
<form name="recipe">
<input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" name="batchVal" value="30" onChange="calculate(malt1); calculate(malt2)"></td>
<input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" name="efficiencyVal" value="75" onChange="calculate(malt1); calculate(malt2)"></td>
</form>
```

Here is the two forms, "mult" and "mult2" that both need the same datainputs from "recipe" form:

```
<form name="mult">
      <select id="malt" name="malt" onChange="UpdateNextField(this,'ppg')">
      <option>Choose fermentable..</option>
      <?php

        $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,maltname,maltebc,maltppg FROM malt WHERE mainid = ?");

        $mainidcolumn = "1";

        /* bind parameters  */
        $query->bind_param("i", $mainidcolumn);
        $query->execute();

        $menu_result = $query->get_result();

        /* now you can fetch the results into an array */
        while ($menu = $menu_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$menu['maltppg'].'">' . $menu['maltname'] . ' ' . $menu['maltebc'] . ' EBC</option>';   

        }
        echo '</select>';
     ?> 

        <input type="text" id="ebcfield" size="1" maxlength="3">
    <input type="text" name="weightVal" size="1" maxlength="5" value="0" onChange="calculate(malt1)">
        <input name="grainpercent" type="text" id="grainpercent" size="1" maxlength="2">
        <input type="text" id="gravity" size="1" value="0" maxlength="4">
        <input name="graincolor" type="text" id="graincolor" size="1" maxlength="3">
        <input type="text" name="ppgVal" id="ppg" onMouseMove="calculate(malt1)">
    </form>

<form name="mult2">
      <select id="malt" name="malt" onChange="UpdateNextField(this,'ppg2')">
      <option>Choose fermentable..</option>
      <?php

        $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,maltname,maltebc,maltppg FROM malt WHERE mainid = ?");

        $mainidcolumn = "1";

        /* bind parameters  */
        $query->bind_param("i", $mainidcolumn);
        $query->execute();

        $menu_result = $query->get_result();

        /* now you can fetch the results into an array */
        while ($menu = $menu_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$menu['maltppg'].'">' . $menu['maltname'] . ' ' . $menu['maltebc'] . ' EBC</option>';   

        }
        echo '</select>';
     ?> 

        <input type="text" id="ebcfield" size="1" maxlength="3">
    <input type="text" name="weightVal2" size="1" maxlength="5" value="0" onChange="calculate(malt2)">
        <input name="grainpercent" type="text" id="grainpercent" size="1" maxlength="2">
        <input type="text" id="gravity2" size="1" value="0" maxlength="4">
        <input name="graincolor" type="text" id="graincolor" size="1" maxlength="3">
        <input type="text" name="ppgVal2" id="ppg2" onMouseMove="calculate(malt2)">
    </form>
```

And finally the javascript that does the calculations based on data in the input fields. Calculate(malt1) and Calculate(malt2) does the same thing, it's just two instances of the same calculation.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function UpdateNextField(which,ppg) {
document.getElementById(ppg).value = which.value;
}

function UpdateNextField(which,ppg2) {
document.getElementById(ppg2).value = which.value;
}

</script>

<!-- calculations for malt 1-5 -->

<!-- form 1 - fermentable 1 -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    function calculate(malt1){
     var weightVal = document.mult.weightVal.value;
     var ppgVal = document.mult.ppgVal.value;
     var batchVal = document.recipe.batchVal.value;
     var efficiencyVal = document.recipe.efficiencyVal.value;
     var showValue = 0;

     var showValue = ((weightVal * ppgVal * 0.000008345) * (efficiencyVal) * 10) / batchVal + (1000);
     showValue = Math.round(showValue * 1) / 1;
     if (!isNaN(showValue)) {
                document.getElementById('gravity').value = showValue;
            }
    }


    function calculate(malt2){
     var weightVal2 = document.mult2.weightVal2.value;
     var ppgVal2 = document.mult2.ppgVal2.value;
     var batchVal = document.recipe.batchVal.value;
     var efficiencyVal = document.recipe.efficiencyVal.value;
     var showValue2 = 0;

     var showValue2 = ((weightVal2 * ppgVal2 * 0.000008345) * (efficiencyVal) * 10) / batchVal + (1000);
     showValue2 = Math.round(showValue2 * 1) / 1;
     if (!isNaN(showValue2)) {
                document.getElementById('gravity2').value = showValue2;
            }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You have duplicate id's and that will give you all sorts of grief. ID's must be unique.

Comment: both functions are called the same and so `calculate(malt1)` overwrites `calculate(malt2)`. Simply naming the arg differently doesn't create a separate function. Try `function calcualteMalt1(arg)` and `calculateMalt2(arg)`

Comment: @LcLk Thanks, that worked. This is what you get with an inexperienced copy paste "developer". I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your function names and duplicate IDs, as noted by Jay and LcLk. But, assuming you fix these, you can save a lot of time and grief by using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). For example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="first" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#first").keypress(function(){
    /* your custom code goes here */
    console.log("A key was pressed.");
});
```

What this says is that anytime a key is pressed while the first input is selected, it will print out `A key was pressed` in the console. You can then either directly call your calculation functions from within that anonymous inner function, or pass them directly into `keypress();`.